# Python2.7 set a given variable to replace one backslash to two backslashes

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I'm still new to programming and working on my first python script.

I'm trying to make my python script execute in a way so the user only has to type this:

```
script.py \\server\location
```

and not execute this this

```
script.py \\\\server\\location
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
import sys

buildpath = sys.argv[1]
buildpath.replace(r'\\', r'\\\\')
print buildpath
```

Any help with this is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not capturing the changed `buildpath` variable after calling `.replace()`. `.replace()` returns the *new* string; strings are immutable so `.replace()` cannot change `buildpath` in-place.

Next, you are using raw strings to define *double* slashes, but you wanted to replace single slashes. Remove the `r` from `r'\\'` and `r'\\\\'`; you cannot use a single slash as the last character in a raw string literal anyway.

I think you wanted to do this instead:

```
buildpath = sys.argv[1]
buildpath = buildpath.replace('\\', '\\\\')
print buildpath
```

Comment: Ah that's a little better and makes sense. But now it is printing this `\\\\stuff\morestuff` and I need it to print this `\\\\stuff\\morestuff`. Any suggestions?

Comment: ah I got it, I just had to change the line without the `raw` tag. This works - `buildpath = buildpath.replace('\\', '\\\\')`. I'll mark you as the answer as soon as 5 minutes are up. Thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: @FiddleFreak: I think your comment and my edit coincided nicely there. :)